# To split a space or comma seperated string into a list in perl

Tags: perl, split

Case :
I have a string `$str = "a, b , c"`
How can I split the string to get a list?
The split expression that I could come up with is :

1. `split('[,\s]+', $str)`
2. `split(/,/, $techoptionGiven);`

The desired behavior
@array = [abc]

Comment: Are the spaces surrounding `b` and `c` supposed to be a part of the data or should they be trimmed away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "a, b , c";

say Dumper split('[,\s]+', $str);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 'a';
$VAR2 = 'b';
$VAR3 = 'c';
```

Personally, I'd want to emphasise the fact that the first argument to `split()` is a regex, not a string.

```
say Dumper split(/[,\s]+/, $str);
```

Comment: You probably don't want to split on space, but on commas with spaces around them. That is, the comma needs to be there: `split /\s*,\s*/, ....`. That way, spaces embedded in a value don't create extra elements.